# Fetch documents where at least one element of an array contains a substring

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document of the following form in MongoDB:

```
product = {
    items : Array
}
```

....sample

```
{
   "items": ["bananas","apples","grapes","guavas","pineapples"]
}
```

I want to fetch all documents where one of the items' elements contains a substring called `apple`

Ideally, `apples` and `pineapples` in the array contain the substring `apple` so the document is supposed to match.

What I've tried with no success

```
let prods = await Product.find({items: {"$in":["apple"]}); //But not working
```

Any ideas of a better way would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to check regular expression condition,

- use `$regex` operator to check the condition

```
let prods = await Product.find({
  items: {
    $regex: "apple"
  }
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/usm1TaAA6pW)